# vncserver - software acceleration check failed

Tags: 14.04, server, vnc

**tl;dr** - VNC Server log has error "software acceleration check failed"

I just installed `vncserver` on Ubuntu 14.04 (Trusty)

Here's my `xstartup` config file

```
#!/bin/sh
# Uncomment the following two lines for normal desktop:

unset SESSION_MANAGER
#exec /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc

gnome-session --session=gnome-classic &
[ -x /etc/vnc/xstartup ] && exec /etc/vnc/xstartup
[ -r $HOME/.Xresources ] && xrdb $HOME/.Xresources

xsetroot -solid grey
vncconfig -iconic &

#x-terminal-emulator -geometry 1280x1024+10+10 -ls -title "$VNCDESKTOP Desktop" &
#x-window-manager &
```

I also double checked that the file is executable

```
jeeves@HAL:~/.vnc $ ls -hlt
total 16K
-rw-rw-r-- 1 jeeves jeeves 1.1K May 24 23:03 HAL:9.log
-rwxrwxr-x 1 jeeves jeeves  406 May 24 23:02 xstartup
-rw------- 1 jeeves jeeves    8 May 24 22:37 passwd
```

I started the server with

```
vncserver -geometry 1680x1050 -nevershared :9
```

I connected on my Mac using the VNC Client Chicken

[image]

And I noticed I was getting a gray screen

[image]

Looking at the vnc server log, it looks like the software acceleration check failed, and I'm not sure what that error is -

```
Xvnc Free Edition 4.1.1 - built Jul 31 2015 19:10:31
Copyright (C) 2002-2005 RealVNC Ltd.
See http://www.realvnc.com for information on VNC.
Underlying X server release 40300000, The XFree86 Project, Inc


Tue May 24 23:05:25 2016
 vncext:      VNC extension running!
 vncext:      Listening for VNC connections on port 5909
 vncext:      created VNC server for screen 0
error opening security policy file /etc/X11/xserver/SecurityPolicy
Could not init font path element /usr/X11R6/lib/X11/fonts/Type1/, removing from list!
Could not init font path element /usr/X11R6/lib/X11/fonts/Speedo/, removing from list!
Could not init font path element /usr/X11R6/lib/X11/fonts/misc/, removing from list!
Could not init font path element /usr/X11R6/lib/X11/fonts/75dpi/, removing from list!
Could not init font path element /usr/X11R6/lib/X11/fonts/100dpi/, removing from list!
Could not init font path element /usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/, removing from list!
Could not init font path element /usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/, removing from list!
Unable to create /home/jeeves/.dbus/session-bus
gnome-session-is-accelerated: No composite extension.
gnome-session-check-accelerated: Helper exited with code 256
gnome-session-is-accelerated: No composite extension.
gnome-session-check-accelerated: Helper exited with code 256
gnome-session[6416]: WARNING: software acceleration check failed: Child process exited with code 1
gnome-session[6416]: CRITICAL: We failed, but the fail whale is dead. Sorry....
```

Thanks!